# Runing time of parallel function in cython

Tags: python, parallel-processing, cython

I have two very simple cython functions working inplace like the following ones (compiled with `-fopenmp`):

```
#cython: language_level=3
#cython: wraparound=False
#cython: boundscheck=False
#cython: nonecheck=False
#cython: cdivision=True

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython
from cython.parallel cimport prange, parallel


def ta_pa(double[:,::1] out, double[:,::1] u, double[:,::1] K, double a):


    cdef Py_ssize_t ix, iz
    cdef Py_ssize_t nx = out.shape[0]
    cdef Py_ssize_t nz = out.shape[1]

    with nogil, parallel():
        for ix in prange(nx):
            for iz in range(nz):
                out[ix, iz] = u[ix, iz] - a*K[ix, iz]

def ta_li(double[:,::1] out, double[:,::1] u, double[:,::1] K, double a):


    cdef Py_ssize_t ix, iz
    cdef Py_ssize_t nx = out.shape[0]
    cdef Py_ssize_t nz = out.shape[1]


    for ix in range(nx):
        for iz in range(nz):
            out[ix, iz] = u[ix, iz] - a*K[ix, iz]
```

When I test these two functions in a notebook with `timeit`, I get the following results with 256x256 arrays :

- `ta_li` : 43.3 µs
- `ta_pa` : 28.1 µs

Until here, all is ok ! but when I replace `ta_li` with `ta_pa` in a bigger script (which runs - among others - this fonction several thousand of times), its execution become much slower than when used with `ta_li` !

- When executing my script with `ta_li`, 1 cpu is in action
- When executing my script with `ta_pa`, 4 cpus are in action
- I used 256x256 arrays in all the tests

I'm sure there is a pertinent explanation to this behavior, but I don't get it. Any hypothesis ?

Comment: Your comparison of running times isn't very useful, because it is only for an (unknown to us) input size: for different sizes of input there will be different speed-ups. I'm sure there are input sizes for which `ta_li` is faster.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mentioned that, of course, I use the functions with the same number of points in my tests and in my script. I updated the post